Confirm the concurrent capabilities of this fair reader writer ticket lock
I'm writing a very simple, shared ticket lock whose goal is to be fair for both readers and writers in the order they arrive.

Everyone gets in the same line
Line-contiguous reader groups get concurrent access
A writer waits for all readers ahead of it and then gets access
After a writer unlocks, the next contiguous reader group gets access

// SharedTicketLock.h
#pragma once
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>

class SharedTicketLock {
    std::atomic<uint16_t> next_ticket{0};
    std::atomic<uint16_t> now_serving{0};
    std::atomic<uint16_t> served{0};

public:
    void writer_lock(){
        uint16_t my_ticket = next_ticket.fetch_add(2);
        while (now_serving.load() != my_ticket || now_serving.load() != served.load()){
            std::this_thread::yield();
        }
    }

    void reader_lock(){
        uint16_t my_ticket = next_ticket.fetch_add(1);
        while (now_serving.load() != my_ticket){
            std::this_thread::yield();
        }
        now_serving.fetch_add(1);
    }

    void writer_unlock(){
        now_serving.fetch_add(2);
        served.fetch_add(2);
    }

    void reader_unlock(){
        served.fetch_add(1);
    }
};


We add an additional atomic counter to the traditional ticket lock: served to track the number of readers in the critical section.
Writers take out two tickets: next_ticket.fetch_add(2), while readers take out just one.
Readers enter when now_serving equals my_ticket.
Writers enter when now_serving equals my_ticket as well as when now_serving equals served, indicating all previous entrants have left the critical section.
When a reader locks, it immediately increments now_serving, which in this implementation is used to determine the in-flight readers and signals to the next entrant that if they are a reader, they may enter. If the next entrant is a writer, it must wait for now_serving and served to be equal.
When a writer locks, it does not increment now_serving, creating a two-ticket gap between the entrant after the writer and causing everyone to wait.
When a reader unlocks, it increments served, which is used by writers to know when all readers before its ticket count have left.
When a writer unlocks, it double increments both next_ticket and now_serving, signaling to the next entrant that a writer has left the critical section and they may now enter.
If the next entrants are readers, they will all enter as each one increments now_serving and checks for a 1 ticket gap.
Ticket overflow is handled implicity as only equality checks are made.

Is my reasoning sound on this?

I would say: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ?

ah, thanks. Hadn't heard of that yet.
